# An example of a sequence of differentiable functions defined on $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

Help me to find an example of a sequence of differentiable functions defined on $[0,1]$ that converge uniformly to a function $f$ on $[0,1]$ such that there exists $x \in (0,1)$ such that $f$ is not differentiable at $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Any continuous function is a uniform limit of polynomials, so pick your favourite non-differentiable continuous function, and that would work!

In fact, if $f$ is such a function, say $f(x) := |x- 0.5|$, then take the sequence to be the sequence of Bernstein polynomials
$$
B_n(f)(x) := \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) x^k (1-x)^{n-k}
$$
Then $B_n(f) \to f$ uniformly.

Edit: A simpler example: Take $f(x) = |x-0.5|$ and consider
$$
f_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2} + f(x)^2}
$$
Then check that $f_n$ is differentiable and
$$
f(x) \leq f_n(x) \leq f(x) + 1/n \quad\forall x\in [0,1]
$$
and so $f_n \to f$ uniformly.

Comment: Perhaps, but it solves the problem efficiently while also indicating how to find such a sequence given a specific function. All desirable qualities in a solution, IMHO.

Comment: I do agree that it's a correct answer that uses a neat result. The original question appears to be at a rather elementary level of real analysis, however. As such, I seriously doubt that this answer is at all useful to the OP.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Is it possible to do it without bernstein polynomials ? i am not introduced to it

Comment: @JamesMatthews: Have posted a simpler example :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the $C^1$-functions
$$f_n(x):=\sqrt{{1\over n^2}+x^2}-{1\over n}\qquad(n\geq1)\ .$$
One has $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$, and
$$f_n(x)={x^2\over \sqrt{{1\over n^2}+x^2}+{1\over n}}\to |x|\qquad(n\to\infty)$$
for all $x\ne0$. It follows that $\lim f_n(x)=|x|$ for all $x\in{\mathbb R}$, which is not differentiable at $0$.